# Citing entire journal issue in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

According to the biblatex-chicago manual the entrytype `periodical` should be used for citing entire journal issues, providing a string such as "special issue" in the `note` field (see pgs. 67, 76, 93, and 96). 
However, `periodical` entries for some reason do not print the `journaltitle` unless I specify it in the `title` field – which is illogical.
The output, as far as I can tell from CMoS 14.178, should be the one generated by `test3` below (which uses the `title` field for the `journaltitle`).

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, 
    bookpages=false, isbn=false, doi=false, numbermonth=false, cmsdate=both]%
    {biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@periodical{test1,
    Date = {2018},
    Editor = {Editor, Edwin},
%   Issuetitle = {This is the Issuetitle},
    Journaltitle = {The Journal},
    Note = {special issue},
    Title = {This is the Issuetitle},
    Volume = {33}}

@periodical{test2,
    Date = {2018},
    Editor = {Feditor, Edwin},
    Issuetitle = {This is the Issuetitle},
    Journaltitle = {The Journal},
    Note = {special issue},
%   Title = {This is the Issuetitle},
    Volume = {33}}

@periodical{test3,
    Date = {2018},
    Editor = {Geditor, Edwin},
    Issuetitle = {This is the Issuetitle},
    Journaltitle = {The Journal},
    Note = {special issue},
    Title = {This shouldn't (need to) be the Journaltitle},
    Volume = {33}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{*}
\printbibliography % print the bibliography 
\end{document}
```

How can I get it to print the `journaltitle` field?
(... and should I report this as a bug?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to think about this is that the `periodical` entry type and `article`/`suppperiodical` are analogous to the `collection` entry type and `incollection`/`suppcollection`. (Same for `book`, `inbook`/`suppbook`.)

So just as you have `title` for `collection`, and `booktitle` for `incollection`/`suppcollection`, you have `title` for `periodical` and `journaltitle` for `article`/`suppperiodical`.

`issuetitle` is the the title of the particular journal volume (if it has one).

If you set things up like this, then cross referencing will work as expected.

At least that's the theory and this is how things work with the standard style. In practice, I notice that the inheritance in `biblatex-chicago` seems to be buggy and not all fields inherit as they should do…

You could experiment with what works and what doesn't and submit bug reports to `biblatex-chicago` as you find issues.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, 
    bookpages=false, isbn=false, doi=false, numbermonth=false, cmsdate=both]%
    {biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{test1,
  Date = {2018},
  Editor = {Editor, Edwin},
  Issuetitle = {The Issue Title},
  Title = {The Journal},
  Volume = {33}
}
@article{test2,
  Author = {Author, Alan},
  Title = {The Article Title},
  Pages = {20-30},
  Crossref = {test1}
}
@collection{test3,
  Date = {2017},
  Editor = {Editor, Edward},
  Title = {The Collection Title},
  Publisher = {Publisher},
  Location = {Location}
}
@incollection{test4,
  Author = {Author, Anthony},
  Title = {The Article Title},
  Pages = {10-20},
  Crossref = {test3}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography % print the bibliography 
\end{document}
```

This gives (which IMHO is wrong, it's missing fields in `test4`):

[image: biblatex chicago output]

Compare with `\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}`:

[image: output with stand biblatex style]

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.  I guess the confusion came from the fact that a book has  one `title` whereas a special issue has two (`issuetitle` and `journaltitle`) and which one will become `title` in the `periodical` is up for grabs (one could argue `issuetitle` should be the `title` (analogous to collections), yet in terms of formatting chicago wants it in italics so that would be a point in favor of `journaltitle` = `title` (doesn't entirely make sense to me). I'll submit a bugreport though, are you aware if `biblatex-chicago` is on github or somewhere?  I couldn't find it on any repository.

Comment: @jan, I don't think it's on github. Try emailing the author.